# Design pattern for creating an object over and over

Tags: xml, parsing

I'm new to design patterns, I have a use case where I need to create the same objects over and over. In my case, I'm parsing a large XML file, and I need to create one object of each  chunk. All the object have the same methods, except for the value stored are different. 
Currently, I'm doing this in a procedural way: create a reader of the XML file, a static method parseEntry takes chunks of , and parse them into a POJO.
I figure there's gotta be a better way of doing this.
Thanks,

Comment: hi, thanks for your answers. I thought about using factory pattern. but from what I read, it's suitable for dealing with different object with the same base class, such as shape. For me, all the objects I'm dealing with are the same, with the same behaviors. do I need to use factory pattern, or maybe just a simple will do to simplify things?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope this idea will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) class using the [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) that generated the objects for you.

Another approach would be to use the [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern, this pattern is very useful in game programming where using Inheritance can overcomplicate the architecture of the game and make objects tightly coupled to each-other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Factory pattern could help.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern